# How to save a method in a class to be executed later

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, methods

I need to know how to pass a method into a class constructor so that it can be called later. The idea is to have a Bullet class that has two properties, a damage integer and a Method that can be called when a bullet of that type has hit an object. The code below should explain a bit better:

```
public class Bullet
{
    public Method OnHit;
    public int Damage;
    public Bullet(int Damage,Method OnHit)
    {
        this.Damage = Damage;
        this.OnHit = OnHit;
    }
}
```

This is so I can make bullets that preform different tasks upon impact by running something like Bullet.OnHit(HitGameObject).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Action` to pass a function to a function then store it in another `Action`. The function that is stored can be called with `Action.Invoke()`.

```
public class Bullet
{
    public int Damage;
    System.Action savedFunc;

    public Bullet(int Damage, System.Action OnHit)
    {
        if (OnHit == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("OnHit");
        }

        this.Damage = Damage;
        savedFunc = OnHit;
    }

    //Somewhere in your Bullet script when bullet damage == Damage
    void yourLogicalCode()
    {
        int someBulletDamage = 30;
        if (someBulletDamage == Damage)
        {
            //Call the function
            savedFunc.Invoke();
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage**:

```
void Start()
{
    Bullet bullet = new Bullet(30, myCallBackMethod);
}

void myCallBackMethod()
{

}
```

Comment: Just an addition. The OP could also use system "delegates" and "events"

Comment: @Cabrra Yes, OP could use raw `delegates` and `events`. it's just that OP wanted to pass in function to a function, then call it later on **NOT** just invoke an event later on. I think that `System.Action` or  `Func` is much more appropriate for this and less code too.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is called delegates in c#,
First you should define method input/output and then you work with methods of this type just like variables.

```
public class Bullet
{
public delegate void OnHit(bool something);
public OnHit onHitMethod;
public int Damage;
public Bullet(int Damage, OnHit OnHit)
{
    this.Damage = Damage;
    this.onHitMethod = OnHit;
}
}
```

in this line `public delegate void OnHit(bool something);` you just defined the type of delegate and in this line `public OnHit onHitMethod;` you defined the method just like a variable.